# Beautiful soup select two item with parent child realtionship

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

The code below finds all the links with gameId and puts the links in a dataframe. My issue is that I am not sure how I store them in a dataframe with the corresponding date. In this case the h2 is the parent tag with the child tag having the links. The code below get the links but how get date for each gameId.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

gmdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['link','gamedate']) 

url = 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/1/year/2020'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
links = soup.select('a')


for link in links:
      if 'gameId' in link.get('href'):
            print(link.get('href'))
            hlink = 'https://www.espn.com' + link.get('href')
            gmdf = gmdf.append({'link': hlink}, ignore_index=True)
```

This line to get the dates on the page but I need the dates with corresponding gameid in the data frame.

```
soup.select('h2')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative method from what Dhivakar has already provided. In it, I add the h2 tag in the original selection by BeautifulSoup, then, I set the date based on when the link does not have an href, since we know it must either be h2 or a tag, and h2 tags contain the dates.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

gmdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['link','gamedate']) 

url = 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/1/year/2020'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
links = soup.select('a, h2')

date = ""
for link in links:
    if link.get('href') is None:
        date = link.text
        print(date)
    elif link.get('href') is not None and 'gameId' in link.get('href'):
        print(date)
        print(link.get('href'))
        hlink = 'https://www.espn.com' + link.get('href')
        gmdf = gmdf.append({'link': hlink, 'gamedate': date}, ignore_index=True)


print(gmdf)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can grab parent and siblings of elements just like in JavaScript.

Replace this after `links = soup.select('a')`,

```
schedule_year = soup.select_one('.automated-header h1').text.split("- ")[-1] # For the schedule year

for link in links:
      if 'gameId' in link.get('href'):
            schedule_date = link.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.previous_sibling.text.split(", ")[-1] + " " + schedule_year # Grabs the h2 tag
            schedule_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(schedule_date, "%B %d %Y") # Converted the date to datetime object for manipulation 
            hlink = 'https://www.espn.com' + link.get('href')
            gmdf = gmdf.append({'link': hlink, 'gamedate': schedule_date}, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a nested loop within a list comprehension to loop those date headers then find the next table and grab the list of href containing the substring of interest (gameId). That way you can have the relevant date listed against each link in a list of tuples you convert to a DataFrame:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/1/year/2020')
soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')

df = pd.DataFrame([('https://www.espn.com' + j['href'], i.text) for i in soup.select(
    '#sched-container .table-caption') for j in i.find_next('table').select('[href*=gameId]')], columns=['link', 'date'])

print(df)
```